facing problem while downgrading tensorflow version in kaggle notebook; what should i do
I wrote a code in tensorflow versino 2.11.0, but recently, my code was not running, and found that current tensorflow version 2.15.0 is the main issue, so I downgrade my version using the code !pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.11.0
But my notebook does find any GPUs, although i enabled the GPU P100 accelerator in my Kaggle notebook like i did before. I also check for GPU in code.
import tensorflow as tf

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():

print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))

else:

print("Please install GPU version of TF")

got

    Please install GPU version of TF


Please help me in this regards. My project deadline is very close
Facing problem while downgrading Tensorflow version in Kaggle notebook.
